# Moving output files from Azure Batch to Data Lake

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-batch

I'm following this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-python) to run a series of python scripts in Azure Batch. These tasks generate a few files that I want to move to a datalake container found in a storage account that is already linked to the batch account where I am running the job. My question is: how can I do this without uploading the keys as part of the resource files? That is, I want the keys to never leave my local computer. Can I access the as environment variables or something like that?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Batch pool managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/managed-identity-pools) where the identity has access to your ADLS. Use the identity in the task to perform the output/upload action.